LuaLaTeX : Error loading module 'ssl.https'
I'm in the middle of migrating a document (my CV/Resume) from xelatex to lualatex.
After setting up my environment, I cannot build a simple document containing Lua code for testing.
Here is some information.
fichier.lua :
-- Chemins de LuaRocks à package.path
package.path = package.path .. ";/opt/homebrew/Cellar/luarocks/3.11.1/share/lua/5.4/?.lua;/opt/homebrew/share/lua/5.4/?.lua;/opt/homebrew/share/lua/5.4/?/init.lua;/opt/homebrew/lib/lua/5.4/?.lua;/opt/homebrew/lib/lua/5.4/?/init.lua;./?.lua;./?/init.lua;/Users/skay/.luarocks/share/lua/5.4/?.lua;/Users/skay/.luarocks/share/lua/5.4/?/init.lua"
package.cpath = package.cpath .. ";/opt/homebrew/lib/lua/5.4/?.so;/opt/homebrew/lib/lua/5.4/loadall.so;./?.so;/Users/skay/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.4/?.so"

print("Package path: " .. package.path)
print("Package cpath: " .. package.cpath)

local https = require("ssl.https")
local ltn12 = require("ltn12")
local json = require("dkjson")

local response = {}
local res, code, headers, status = https.request{
    url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
    sink = ltn12.sink.table(response)
}

if res then
    print("Code de statut : " .. code)
    local body = table.concat(response)
    local data, pos, err = json.decode(body, 1, nil)
    if err then
        print("Erreur de décodage JSON: " .. err)
    else
        for i, post in ipairs(data) do
            print("Post " .. i .. ": " .. post.title)
        end
    end
else
    print("Erreur : " .. code)
end

main.tex :
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}

hi

\begin{luacode*}
kpse.set_program_name("luatex")

package.path = package.path .. ";/opt/homebrew/Cellar/luarocks/3.11.1/share/lua/5.4/?.lua;/opt/homebrew/share/lua/5.4/?.lua;/opt/homebrew/share/lua/5.4/?/init.lua;/opt/homebrew/lib/lua/5.4/?.lua;/opt/homebrew/lib/lua/5.4/?/init.lua;./?.lua;./?/init.lua;/Users/skay/.luarocks/share/lua/5.4/?.lua;/Users/skay/.luarocks/share/lua/5.4/?/init.lua"
package.cpath = package.cpath .. ";/opt/homebrew/lib/lua/5.4/?.so;/opt/homebrew/lib/lua/5.4/loadall.so;./?.so;/Users/skay/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.4/?.so"

-- tex.print("Package path: " .. package.path)
-- tex.print("Package cpath: " .. package.cpath)

dofile("fichier.lua")
\end{luacode*}

\end{document}

Luarocks list :
$ luarocks --local --lua-version 5.4 list

Rocks installed for Lua 5.4 in /Users/skay/.luarocks
----------------------------------------------------

dkjson
   2.8-1 (installed) - /Users/skay/.luarocks/lib/luarocks/rocks-5.4

luasocket
   3.1.0-1 (installed) - /Users/skay/.luarocks/lib/luarocks/rocks-5.4

When I run the lua script alone, everything works fine.
But when I try to compile my PDF file with :

lualatex --shell-escape main.tex

I get this error...
texmf-dist/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-basic-merged.lua:404: error loading module 'ssl.https' from file '/opt/homebrew/lib/lua/5.4/ssl.so':
        dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/lua/5.4/ssl.so, 0x0006): symbol not found in flat nam
espace '_lua_newuserdatauv'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in local 'f'
        ...4/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-basic-merged.lua:404: in local 'loo
kup'
        ...4/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-basic-merged.lua:429: in function <
...4/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-basic-merged.lua:419>
        [C]: in function 'require'
        fichier.lua:8: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'dofile'
        [\directlua]:13: in main chunk.
\luacode@dbg@exec ...code@maybe@printdbg {#1} #1 }
                                                  
l.23 \end{luacode*}

Thank you for any help you can give me.

LuaTeX uses Lua 5.3, but lua_newuserdatauv requires Lua 5.4. Try installing the 5.3 version. (Also, LuaTeX already has luasocket built in to it, but I can't remember if it supports TLS or not).


package.path = package.path .. ";/opt/homebrew/Cellar/luarocks/3.11.1/share/lua/5.4/?.lua;/opt/homebrew/share/lua/5.4/?.lua;/opt/homebrew/share/lua/5.4/?/init.lua;/opt/homebrew/lib/lua/5.4/?.lua;/opt/homebrew/lib/lua/5.4/?/init.lua;./?.lua;./?/init.lua;/Users/skay/.luarocks/share/lua/5.4/?.lua;/Users/skay/.luarocks/share/lua/5.4/?/init.lua"
package.cpath = package.cpath .. ";/opt/homebrew/lib/lua/5.4/?.so;/opt/homebrew/lib/lua/5.4/loadall.so;./?.so;/Users/skay/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.4/?.so"


LuaTeX uses Lua 5.3.6, but you're trying to load a binary module built for Lua 5.4, which won't work. One solution would be to install a module built for Lua 5.3; but since LuaTeX already embeds luasocket, it's much easier to just use that:
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Initialization %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
    if not package.loaded.socket then
        luatexbase.module_error("example", [[
            Module ``luasocket'' not available.

            Please compile with either ``lualatex --shell-escape'' or
            ``lualatex --socket'' to enable the ``luasocket'' module.
    ]])
    end

    local http = require "socket.http"
    local json = utilities.json


    ---------------------------
    --- Get JSON from a URL ---
    ---------------------------

    local function get_json(url)
        local body, code, headers = http.request(url)

        if code >= 400 then
            return nil
        end

        return json.tolua(body)
    end


    -------------------------------
    --- Get a field from a post ---
    -------------------------------

    local function get_post_field(url, post_index, field_name)
        local posts = get_json(url)
        if not posts then return end

        local post = posts[post_index]
        if not post then return end

        return post[field_name]
    end


    ------------------------------
    --- Define the TeX command ---
    ------------------------------

    local function tex_get_post_field()
        local url        = token.scan_string()
        local post_index = tonumber(token.scan_string())
        local field_name = token.scan_string()
        tex.sprint(get_post_field(url, post_index, field_name) or "error")
    end

    local luafunc_index = luatexbase.new_luafunction("tex_get_post_field")
    lua.get_functions_table()[luafunc_index] = tex_get_post_field
    token.set_lua("getpostfield", luafunc_index, "global")
\end{luacode*}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Demonstration %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
    \getpostfield{https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts}{1}{title}
\end{document}


